# How to import models with multiple-outputs in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, keras, deep-learning, onnx

I'm trying to import a pre-trained Faster R-CNN model in ONNX (or Keras) format to MATLAB, however I get the error that Models with multiple outputs are not supported yet. 
Is there a way around this problem?

I have tried importONNXNetwork and importKerasNetwork.

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature is not currently supported in the MATLAB ONNX backend. I would suggest raising an issue on the ONNX github.